# WCF SOAP Action

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am rewriting a legacy asp.net web service in WCF 4.0. My obvious end-goal would be that the new endpoints would exactly match the legacy ones. The problem i encountered is that in the legacy web service they exposed the soap actions as: http://www.my-domain.com/my-action. In WCF from my research it needs to be like: http://www.my-domain/my-service-contract/my-action. I found that you can alter the service contract descriptor by changing the "Name" parameter to the service contact namespace attribute. From my research it seems like there is no way to completely remove this from the exposed soap action. Anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [OperationContractAttribute.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action.aspx) property you can specify the entire string.